# How do I overcome this error when launching the app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter

Hey I recently started with flutter and trying to launch the default flutter app on an iOS device.

**I get this error when I try launching it. Any thoughts?**

[screenshot from xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJnWc.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Have tried run it through android studio or VS code, these are recommended platform for flutter development even on macbook. Please let us know if that resolves the issue